# How Can i print emoji in notepad using micro pro

Tags: c++, windows, arduino, emoji

I want to print emoji in windows usinf Arduino pro micro. I have create a code that is printing emoji, but only in Serial monitor not in notepad.

Thank you in advance

```
String emoji[] {
  "\U0001F620", // fist  
  "\U0001F60D", // eyes
  "\U00002764" // heart
};
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
Serial.println(emoji[0]);
}
```

Comment: How is your Arduino connected to notepad?

Comment: Can you use a hex editor to show the exact bytes that are printed to your file?

Comment: use the Keyboard library